# Cakephp 2.2.3 JS Submit button. How to add Attributes to the element

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I can't see how to add attributes to CakePHP buttons.  For example, data-loading-text="Loading..."

How can I add data attributes like this to my buttons?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-buttons-and-submit-elements
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html

Answer (score 2):

Any keys/values in the second array argument which Cake doesn't recognise should end up as HTML attributes. Try something like

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', array(
    'data-loading-text'=>'Loading...')
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write my Q very well.  This works for regular submit elements, but not for JS->submit. It tries to add it in to the Javascript

Comment: Perhaps I didn't _read_ your Q very well :) I don't have a direct answer for you unfortunately. Looking at the source for JsHelper, it does just what you describe. You could either extendhttp://api.cakephp.org/view_source/js-helper#l-415, which identifies which keys in `$options` are passed to `FormHelper->submit()` (I think allowing all `data-` attributes makes sense), or just use FormHelper directly and write your own JS (or copy what JsHelper generates, then stop using it).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Js->submit('Procurar', array(
'class' => 'btn yellow',
'htmlAttributes' => array('data-loading-text'=>'Loading...')
));
```